# Overriding Layout

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides

[Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html) are the official documents. I am using "porto" as the parent theme, and "porto_base_child" as its child theme. In the backend I have porto_base_child selected for all store views. For the parent theme, when I add

```
remove='true'
```

to the referenceContainer for the footer, it removes the footer. That is as expected - good!

However, when I try to modify the same line within my child theme, it doesn't stick. Rather, it always inherits the value from the parent, instead of overriding it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, painfully. It is exactly as the link I posted above describes it. Yesterday I tried and it didn't work. Must have been that I spelled a folder wrong. Magento is very unforgiving.

Below is an image of my file structure. The parent them is porto, and the child is porto_base_child. I wanted to override "default.xml" within porto/Smarwave_Porto/layout.

You can see that for overriding this layout, multiple new folders were required, such that the path looks like this:

```
porto_base_child/Smartwave_Porto/layout/override/theme/Smartwave/porto/default.xml
```

[image]